# google.maps.InfoWindow is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-earth, infowindow

If anyone encountered the same problem and come up with the solution please give me an idea if what's wrong with this code.

The InfoWindow is not working when i click the map polygon.

All parts are working except for InfoWindow Pop up.

```
function initialize() {



var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.63276, 122.27588),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var arr = new Array();
  var polygons = [];
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + "/polygon/xml",
    async: !0,
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(t) {
      var xml = xmlParse(getXmlString(t));
      var subdivision = xml.getElementsByTagName("Subdivision");
      for (var i = 0; i < subdivision.length; i++) {
        arr = [];
        var coordinates = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Subdivision")[i].getElementsByTagName("coord");
        for (var j = 0; j < coordinates.length; j++) {
          arr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(coordinates[j].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(coordinates[j].getAttribute("lng"))
          ));
          bounds.extend(arr[arr.length - 1])
        }
        polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: arr,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          fillColor: '#FFF000',
          fillOpacity: 0.8
        }));        
        polygons[polygons.length - 1].setMap(map);

        // xxx
        google.maps.event.addListener(polygons[polygons.length - 1], 'click', function(e) {
          var content = "<div class='infowindow'>";
          content += "Latitude: " + e.latLng.lat() + "<br/>";
          content += "Longitude: " + e.latLng.lng() + "</div>";
          showInfoWindow(e.latLng, content);
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
        // zzz

      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  });
}

function showInfoWindow(latLng, content) {
  // alert(latLng);
  // alert(content);
  infoWindow.setContent('Rollie');
  infoWindow.setPosition(latLng);
  infoWindow.open(map);
}

function getXmlString(xml) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    return xml.xml;
  }
  return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
}

function xmlParse(str) {
  if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return createElement('div', null);
}

var baseUrl = "http://" + document.domain + ":8080";
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the clickable attribute to true:

```
polygons.push(
    new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: arr,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      fillColor: '#FFF000',
      fillOpacity: 0.8,
      clickable: true
    })
);
```

I don't remember if it's enabled by default.